# JQuery tr remove() weird behaviour in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

I am trying to loop thru a table s and remove them if it doesn't contains a keyword.

The code works, it doesn't throwing any exceptions.
And I can debug and see that all correct.
But it removes all the tr only for 1-2 seconds than table returns back.

```
   function search() {

   var keyword = $('#tbId').val();
   $('#tableid').find('tr').each(function () {

           if ($(this).html().indexOf(keyword) == -1) {
                  $(this).remove();}

                                 });
     };
```

PLEASE HELP!!

Comment: are you getting any js error?

Comment: There is nothing shown here that would regenerate the table. There must be something else on your page that is refreshing or reloading data. Please create a working demonstration so that we can experience the problem.

Comment: Sorry can't do the demonstration. It is asp. net form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED!

script is working.
Problem was because postback happening in background.